# idssphp duping array in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

OK...

your answer is fine @Random, however it's still duping the ids, so i integrated your code to my dev code... so here's my final code....

```
$gr = mysql_query("select id from permission_sets");
$permission_arr = array(
'start_perms'  => isset($_POST['START_'.$id]),
'reply_perms'  => isset($_POST['REPLY_'.$id]),
'read_perms'   => isset($_POST['READ_'.$id]),
'upload_perms' => isset($_POST['UPLOAD_'.$id]),
'show_perms'   => isset($_POST['SHOW_'.$id]),
'download_perms' => isset($_POST['DOWNLOAD_'.$id]));

// saving the beginning of the line : "group: 1,2,3"
$header = 'PID: ';
$read   = "";
$reply  = "";
$start  = "";
$upload = "";
$download = "";
$show   = "";
$subPIDs = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($gr)){
foreach($row as $pid){
//-----------------------------
// Get perm id and set it..
//-----------------------------
$pid = $pid.",";


if($permission_arr['start_perms'] == 1){
$start .= $pid;
$subPIDs .= $start;
}
if($permission_arr['read_perms'] == 1){
$read .= $pid;
$subPIDs .= $read;
}
if($permission_arr['reply_perms'] == 1){
$reply .= $pid;
$subPIDs .= $reply;
}
if($permission_arr['upload_perms'] == 1){
$upload .= $pid;
$subPIDs .= $upload;
}
if($permission_arr['download_perms'] == 1){
$download .= $pid;
$subPIDs .= $download;
}
if($permission_arr['show_perms'] == 1){
$show .= $pid;
$subPIDs .= $show;
}
$header .= $subPIDs;
}

} // End while

//------------------------------------
// Store the data in a new array..
//------------------------------------
$perm_arr = array(
'start_perms'  => $start,
'reply_perms'  => $reply,
'read_perms'   => $read,
'upload_perms' => $upload,
'show_perms'   => $show,
'download_perms' => $download);
$head = $header.' = ';
foreach($perm_arr as $key => $val){
if($val){
$head .= $key.'<br>'.$head;
}
}

print $head;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($perm_arr);
```

this does everything yours does... we just need to stop dupes in the output, in the array is no dupe, only in output... also when i mark only 1 box ihe array gets all or no ids...

Comment: what is the goal of your output ? the use of `$k` looks useless. Show a precise sample of the output you wish (with the associated database sample)

Comment: my current output is:

Comment: group: 2 = read_perms,
group: 2 = upload_perms,
group: 2 = show_perms,

Comment: i want: group: 1,2 = download_perms, //etc  download_perms >>> are $k

Comment: how do you wish to have `group: 1,2 = download_perms`. What case in database should make this output ? can you edit your answer and add a var_dump of your rows please ?

Comment: What? I'm only grabbing the id frrom  DB atm nothing else..

Comment: Ok for the IDs in DB. What about permissions now ? You want `group: {list of all IDs in DB} = download_perms`, so what means the `etc` ? you want the same output for all permissions ? Don't you ever need the boolean values in your `$permission_arr` to say which permission to print ?

Comment: You hit it m8, exactly what i want.... no don't need boolean value however if i xdon't mark the box, i want the id to be missed...

Comment: can some1 please heplp......

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
// list of permissions with boolean
$permission_arr = array(
    'start_perms'  => isset($_POST['START_'.$id]),
    'reply_perms'  => isset($_POST['REPLY_'.$id]),
    'read_perms'   => isset($_POST['READ_'.$id]),
    'upload_perms' => isset($_POST['UPLOAD_'.$id]),
    'show_perms'   => isset($_POST['SHOW_'.$id]),
    'download_perms' => isset($_POST['DOWNLOAD_'.$id]));

echo 'sql';
$gr = mysql_query("select id from permission_sets");
// saving the beginning of the line : "group: 1,2,3"
$header = 'group: ';
$separator = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($gr)) {
    foreach($row as $g){
        $header .= $separator.$g;
        $separator = ',';
    }
}
$header = $header.' = ';
foreach($permission_arr as $k => $p){
    if($p) {
        // the permission is OK, we print this permission
        // output like "group: 1,2,3 = start_perms, <br>"
        print $header.$k.", <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: hi just got back, that don't work.... errrmmm it's outpurt:group: 2,2 = start_permsreply_perms, show_perms, download_perms,
group: 3,3 = start_permsreply_perms, show_perms, download_perms,  that 1st one shud be: group: 2,3 = start_perms, group: 2 = reply_perms, group: 2,3 = show_perms, group: 2,3 = download_perms,

Comment: Is there a typo for your reply_perm ? because I don't get the logic why there is only "group: 2" instead of "group: 2,3" for this permission ? If it is actually the output you wish, how do you define that ID 2 got reply perm but not ID 3 ?

Comment: Yea typo, sorry.. Ideally i want 6 liin

Comment: Yea typo, sorry.. Ideally i want 6 liones with group id an pem

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer then. So if the group doesn't have the permission (i.e the boolean is false in the `$permission_arr`), do you agree ?

Comment: missing a part in last comment : if the group doesn't have the permission, we won't show this permission (so there can be less than 6 lines)

Comment: please see my 1st question.

Comment: You are are too muxh mixing... the code in my answer should replace your code, not go after. In your new question, you are using subPIDs which contains the same id multiple times, which is useless.

Comment: I misplaced the $header definition. Please see my edited answer (also corrected a typo with `$header`. The problem in your code is the `$subPIDs` variable, that contain the ids of ALL permissions concatenated. If you only use `$show`, you only have PIDs list once (if you have show_permission